# Handler "PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" has a bad module "IsapiModule" in its module list

Tags: asp.net, iis

Im getting the following error in 32 bit machine **classic applicationpool**

```
     Handler "PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" has a bad module "IsapiModule" in its module list.
```

and in 64 bit machine

Handler "PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" has a bad module "IsapiModule" in its module list.

If we install isapi and cgi in webservices then this error is not coming. Is there any possible way to allow my program without installiing those in classic applicationpool. and my next  question is, how to recognize the isapi and cgi restrictions are installed. Is there any registry check exists or any other check.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may also occur for other handlers e.g. I had the error: "SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" has a bad module "IsapiModule"

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The above answer helped me but needed some additional steps, here is the full process I had to do.

Go to **Control panel** -> **Programs and Features** -> **Turn Windows features on or off**. Make sure you have the following selected:

[image: Turn Windows features on or off]

Next, refresh IIS Manager. You should now see **ISAPI and CGI restrictions** on the root level of features of IIS, **click Allow for both versions of .NET v4.0**

[image: ISAPI and CGI restrictions]

Comment: Thank you for your code. Before this, we have install asp.net 4.0 in iis. Open visual studio command prompt (Run as admin) type bellow command :   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319> aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Comment: And this is solution for Visual Studio 4.5 application host in IIS 7.5.

Comment: It worked! Only that I had to close and reopen IIS 7.5 to show "ISAPI and CGI restrictions", as refresh only didn't work.

Answer (score 9):

did you enabled asp.net for IIS in **programs and features** ? check it in 
programs and features -> Turn windows features on or off -> internet information service -> world wide web services -> application development features -> asp.net !

Comment: i had this same problem and this answer fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add: if there is more than one framework on the machine, please install the framework in IIS by using 'aspnet_regiis -i', which is the .NET framework home directory (e.g. on my machine, is `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on a 2016 server.  I found an answer that solved my problem in 1 minute after spending HOURS trying to resolve it on my own.
https://forums.iis.net/t/1149768.aspx

Steps from that page that worked:
1. Take IIS backup.
2. Open IIS
3. Click on server module node at the top of the left hand tree and choose "Modules".
4. Right click on DynamicCompressionModule and choose "Unlock"
5. Right click on StaticCompressionModule and choose "Unlock".
6. Open desired websites -> Open Modules.
7. Right click on DynamicCompressionModules and choose "remove".
8. Right click on StaticCompressionModule and choose "Remove".
9. Do IISRESET.